# Simple AJAX button click (server is local) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, localhost

I'm very new to AJAX and I have tried one of the easiest things (I thought), to load a HTML webpage, click a button and make an alert box appear. For some reason all the examples I've tried (with GET, POST, different syntax, ...) won't work. My webserver is local, I use node js, express and ejs. And there seem to be a lot of examples of this button click on the internet, but nothing about a local server has worked. The browser I test in is Google Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('btn').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/gebruikerpagina',
            'type': 'POST',
            succes: function(st){
              if(st === "succes"){
                alert('Clicked');
              }  
            }
        })
    }); 
}); 
</script>

<button type="button" id="btn">Change Content</button>
```

This is in my HTML file (also jquery is imported in the head), and the next code is in my js:

```
app.post('/gebruikerpagina', function(req,res){
    res.render('../gebruikerpagina')
});
```

Comment: You have a typo: `succes` should be `success`.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that, thanks! But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Second typo, `btn` should be `#btn` for the selector

Comment: Check the console if there is an error

Comment: You're right, no idea why I did that, but still no alert box.

Comment: `success` callback ok, what about an `error` callback? Maybe your app is trying to tell you things, but you're not listening. Also, `if(st === "succes")` will never be satisfied because you don't send back the word "success", you're sending back a whole rendered page.

Comment: `if(st === "succes"){` <= should this also be `success`?  I mean, I think it should be fairly apparent at this point that some general debugging using a console log would get you a long ways towards solving this yourself...

Comment: No error at all in the console, nothing happens when I click the button, not even an error.

Comment: And yes, a few `console.log()` wouldn't be too much here

Comment: If the button exists in DOM, I would use `.click()` versus `.on()` method.

Comment: Everything you guys said was right and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Twisty What's the difference? `.click()` calls `.on()`. He's not using delegation syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "./gebruikerpagina",
      type: "POST",
      succes: function(st) {
        console.log(st);
        if (st === "success") {
          console.log("Success");
        }
      },
      error: function(x, e, t) {
        console.log(e, t);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Change Content</button>
```

Code of this nature will provide more feedback to the Console and will be easier to diagnose. This code also uses the correct Selector.

Se More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/